# auto increment variable in bigquery

Tags: google-bigquery, auto-increment

I have a table in google bigquery of the form:

```
id      value
798     <val>
879     <val>
774     <val>
23      <val>
```

And I want to build a table of the form:

```
id    value    int_var
798   <val>    1
879   <val>    2
774   <val>    3
23    <val>    4
```

where the variable int_var is a simple incremental variable. Can someone help me?

Comment: How do you define the order for that int_var?

Comment: no order, I just want to associate a unique integer between 1 and the number of rows in my table. I even accept any unique number between 1 and let say 10000000

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
SELECT 
  id, 
  value, 
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER() AS int_var
FROM YourTable
```

Comment: Actually windowed function such as `ROW_NUMBER()` and `RANK()` will become a big problem once you deal with billions of data

Comment: @Bongsky - very true. there are many new post since this one that addresses this issue

Comment: I will check and let you know o:)